# Understanding a proof that if $|x|<1$ then $x^n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

The question:

[image]

The answer:

[image]

I understand the answer of $(d)$ but I don't know how to put "$\alpha= 0$" in order to get the solution of $(e)$.

Help?

Comment: Your question is rather different from your title

Comment: Note that $n^0=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$, it is trivial. Otherwise, asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$ is equivalent to asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x|^n=0$. But$$|x|^n=\frac1{(1/|x|)^n}.$$So, take $p=\frac1{|x|}-1$.

Comment: Thanks. Another question, what would this proof fail in if $|x|$ were $\ge1$ (i.e $p\le0$)?

Comment: @AbduMagdy As a direct application of (d), yes, it would fail.

Comment: In what it would fail? May you specify, please?

Comment: If, say, $\alpha=0$ and $p=-\frac12$, then it is not true that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}=0.$$Actually, in the case the limit os $+\infty$.

Comment: I really thank you but I mean in the proof reasoning itself. For instance why will $(1+p)^n$ not be greater than $(nCk)p^k$?

Comment: Not necessarily. SInce $p<0$, some terms of the binomial expansion of $(1+p)^n$ will be negative. So, the argument doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience; I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $\alpha=0$ the last inequality becomes

$$0<\frac{1}{(1+p)^n}<\frac{2^kk!}{p^kn^k}$$

Answer (score 1):

The hint is trying to say:

Set $\alpha=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{p+1}$ in (d). Note that $x= \frac{1}{p+1} \Leftrightarrow p = \frac{1}{x}-1>0$.

Comment: Thanks. Another question, what would this proof fail in if $|x|$ were $\ge1$ (i.e $p\le0$)?

Comment: If $p <0$ then the inequality $(1+p)^n > \binom{n}{k}p^k$ may not hold and the inequalities $$ \binom{n}{k}p^k > \frac{n^k}{2^k k!}p^k$$ and the last inequality in (d) would fail for $k$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\alpha=0$ so that part (d) tells us that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^0}{(1+p)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+p)^n}=0$$
then since $p>0$ we have $0<\frac{1}{1+p}<1$